# ITunes connect not showing app after 24 hours

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, app-store-connect, publishing

I build a mobile app using ionic and uploaded through xcode. It has been more than 24 hours but I can't still see any option to add my app yet. It still says Submit your builds using Xcode 6 or later, or Application Loader 3.0 or later. Also, if I go to activities tab, I can't see any builds under all builds.

Appreciate any help,

Jay

Comment: I have not used ionic before, but seen this behavior. Try uploading another build, that might fix it. If it still doesn't work, you will need to call Apple.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the version number and re-archived it...  Uploaded again using Xcode and now I can see my app under activities tab

Answer (score 0):

Wait for 15-20 minutes then it will be available for selection in the build section. Did you get any issues/error or warnings at time of binary upload?

Comment: As I mentioned, I waited for 24 hours and there was no errors but I had to change the version number re-archived it and upload it again.

Comment: Is it available now for submission?